# Is the polynomial $4x^3 - 3x - 1/2 $ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, rational-numbers

Not sure where to go since there's a fraction 1/2.
Could I look at 
$8x^3 - 6x -1$?

Comment: I think you mean $8x^3 - 6x - 1$. Since it is cubic, if it factors it has a root, so you can use the rational root test.

Comment: I recognize the cubic $8*x^3-6*x-1$ it root is $-\cos(2*\pi/9)$ it is an example casus irreducible polynomial, so it's roots can't be expressed in radical without complex number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $8x^3-6x-1=(2x)^3-3(2x)-1$, your polynomial is irreducible if and only if the polynomial $x^3-3x-1$ is irreducible. By the rational root theorem, the only rationals that can possibly be roots of this polynomial are $\pm1$. But none of them is. And a cubic polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ without rational roots is irreducible.